# java.lang.AssertionError - Mockito test in many threads fails

Tags: java, mockito

I have many tests which work on my computer (because they are run one by one, not in many threads) but they fail on remote server.

**How to forbid this class from running in parallel?** I also have many different classes, that can work in parallel, but in this class, mock behaviour should be different in each test.
While running in parallel I guess that there is no control on instance variable:

```
 @Mock
    private EventDao eventDao;
```

and it behaves randomly, thats why the assertion error occurs?

I guess the reason is:

```
doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> eventModel).when(eventDao).loadEvent(anyObject(), anyObject());
```

and each test records this mock:

```
       @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class HoldServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private EventDao eventDao;
    @InjectMocks
    private EventServiceImpl eventService = new EventServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void shouldEventBeProcessed() {
        EventModel eventModel = createEvent();
        doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> eventModel).when(eventDao).loadEvent(anyObject(), anyObject());
        eventService.processEvent(eventModel);
        assertTrue(eventModel.isProcessed());
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldEventBeRed() {
        EventModel eventModel = createEvent();
        doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> eventModel).when(eventDao).loadEvent(anyObject(), anyObject());
        eventService.processEventRed(eventModel);
        assertTrue(eventModel.isRed());
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldEventBeGreen() {
        EventModel eventModel = createEvent();
        doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> eventModel).when(eventDao).loadEvent(anyObject(), anyObject());
        eventService.processEventGreen(eventModel);
        assertTrue(eventModel.isGreen());
    }
}
```

Comment: Chances are, that your EventServiceImpl is not threadsafe and/or contains static parts that make problem in a multi-thread environment. Unfortunately, without that code, that's hard to say.